# How to pass object containing list of other custom objects to call REST service using HttpPost

Tags: java, json, rest, http-post

I am trying to call REST service by passing object as parameter which contains list of other custom objects. I am getting "Error 405: Request method POST not supported" error.
Client side code-

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory()).build();

        httpPost = new HttpPost("http://api100.abc.xyz.com:9080/abcd/api/sscws/v1/saveContributions");
        httpPost.addHeader(WebAppConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, WebAppConstants.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpPost.addHeader(WebAppConstants.ACCEPT, WebAppConstants.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpPost.addHeader(WebAppConstants.X_USERNAME, userContext.getUserID());
        httpPost.addHeader(WebAppConstants.X_ENTERPRISE_ID, "123456");
        httpPost.addHeader(WebAppConstants.X_UNIQUE_ID, "A548742ATG");  //to do

        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String requestParamJson = ow.writeValueAsString(contribRequestParamDto);

        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(contribRequestParamDto, WebAppConstants.UTF_8));
```

In above code contribRequestParamDto is a object of ContributionsRequestParamDto class which will look this-

```
public class ContributionsRequestParamDto {

private String tokenID;
private String taxID;
private String affiliateID;
private long planID;
private String accountNumber;
private String bankAccountNumber;
private String transitId;
private BigDecimal eftAmt;
private Date ppeDate;
private String taxYear;
private Short planType;

private List<ParticipantsDeferralDto> participantsDeferrals;
private List<EmployersContributionDto> employersContributions;
```

}

REST endpoint will look like this-

```
 @Transactional
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@Api(value="v1", description="")
public class SscRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveContributions", 
            method=RequestMethod.POST, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ApiOperation(value="Returns the saved contributions object")
    public String saveContributions(@RequestBody ContributionsRequestParam contributionsParam) throws Exception {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Json request body is-

```
{
      "tokenID" : "123456789",
      "taxID" : "123456",
      "affiliateID" : "123456789",
      "planID" : 123456,
      "ppeDate" : "2017-10-24",
      "taxYear" : "2017",
      "planType" : 1,
      "participantsDeferrals" : [ {
        "taxId" : "555555",
        "participantDeferralAmt" : 22.00
      } ],
      "employersContributions" : [ {
        "taxId" : "555555",
        "employerContributionAmt" : 22.00
      } ]
    }
```

This is not working as I am getting "Error 405: Request method POST not supported" error. It will work if remove list fields for 'participantsDeferrals' and 'employersContributions' from JSON request body by removing those list fields from 'ContributionsRequestParamDto' object. So I am sure that there is something wrong with list of custom objects and its corresponding JSON request body. Am I missing something here? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the type of the Date. Now it is normal String and not SQL date. After changing its type to string in object, it is working fine